# Extracting specific charaters on different lines in Java

Tags: java

I have a file "file.txt" in Java. In the file I have the following values:

```
10 10
3 3 W
MMMMMRM
4 4 R
LRLRLML
```

I want to read each line and with each character I want to assign them to a variable which I will use for calculation.
Any idea with how I can proceed with?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**1)** You can use a `BufferedReader` with the `readLine()` method to read each line.

**2)** Then you can use `split()` for each word or `toCharArray()` for each character.

**3)** Then assign said character to predefined variables.

*It would be helpful if we could see what you've tried so far or if you could give more details on what you are trying to accomplish.*

Comment: Why use `split()`. `toCharArray()` will do it. But if every character needs to be assigned to a different variable, then `charAt()` would be even better.

Comment: That is right. Forgot about that one. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Crazy Ninja and Seda Kunda